# R convert data.frame to json

Tags: arrays, json, r

I'm trying to convert a data.frame into json format

my data.frame has the following structure

```
a   <- rep(c("Mario", "Luigi"), each = 3)
b   <- sample(34:57, size = length(a))
df  <- data.frame(a,b)
> df
      a  b
1 Mario 43
2 Mario 34
3 Mario 36
4 Luigi 45
5 Luigi 52
6 Luigi 35
```

What I want to create is something like this (to finally print it to a .json file)

```
[
  {
    "a": "Mario",
    "b": [43, 34, 36]
  },
  {
    "a": "Luigi",
    "b": [45, 52, 35]
  }
]
```

I've tried different packages handling json format but so far failed to produce this kind of output. I usually end up with something like this

```
[
  {
   "a":"Mario",
   "b":43
  },
  {
   "a":"Mario",
   "b":34
  },
  {
   "a":"Mario",
   "b":36
  },
  {
   "a":"Luigi",
   "b":45
  },
  {
   "a":"Luigi",
   "b":52
  },
  {
   "a":"Luigi",
   "b":35
  }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you nest `b` as a list column, it will convert correctly:

```
library(jsonlite)

# converts b to nested list column
df2 <- aggregate(b ~ a, df, list)

df2
##       a          b
## 1 Luigi 49, 42, 37
## 2 Mario 46, 50, 45

toJSON(df2, pretty = TRUE)
## [
##   {
##     "a": "Luigi",
##     "b": [49, 42, 37]
##   },
##   {
##     "a": "Mario",
##     "b": [46, 50, 45]
##   }
## ]
```

or if you prefer dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(b = list(b)) %>% 
    toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
```

or data.table:

```
library(data.table)

toJSON(setDT(df)[, .(b = list(b)), by = a], pretty = TRUE)
```

which both return the same thing.

Comment: This is a better approach for this example - happy to have my 'tick' taken away :)

Comment: Agreed, seems like the more general approach!

Answer (score 2):

To get the required JSON structure you will want your data in a list, something like:

```
l <- list(list(a = "Mario",
               b = c(43,34,36)),
          list(a = "Luigi",
               b = c(45,52,35)))

## then can use the library(jsonlite) to convert to JSON

library(jsonlite)

toJSON(l, pretty = T)

[
  {
    "a": ["Mario"],
    "b": [43, 34, 36]
  },
  {
    "a": ["Luigi"],
    "b": [45, 52, 35]
  }
]
```

So to split your data into this format, you can do

```
l <- lapply(unique(df$a), function(x) list(a = x, b = df[a == x,"b"])   )

## and then the conversion works
toJSON(l, pretty = T)

[
  {
    "a": ["Mario"],
    "b": [44, 49, 50]
  },
  {
    "a": ["Luigi"],
    "b": [39, 57, 35]
  }
]
```

This works for the simple case, but if it gets more complex it might be better to re-design how you create your data.frame, and instead create a list(s) to begin with.

---

*Reference*

The [jsonlite vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) is a very good resource.