# R converse table to JSON type

Tags: r

I am having the following table

```
country city area population  
   AA    A    Q    50  
   AA    B    R    23
   BB    C    T    200  
   BB    c    Z    10
```

So, I want to create a JSON file out of it *while* nesting if parameters are same.
Expected output:

```
{  
"country":  
{"AA":{  
      "city":{  
        "A":{"area":{"Q":50}},  
        "B":{"area":{"R":23}}
}}},  
"BB":{  
      "city":{  
        "C":{"area":{"Q":50, "Z":10}
}
}}}}
```

}

Is there some neat way to do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215331/convert-tibble-dataframe-to-nested-json-with-arrays

Comment: Could you try 'toJSON(df)' from 'jsonlite' package